# Help with constructing "yesterday I took a nap for a half hour" in Japanese

Tags: translation

I tried (at least) to construct a sentence. However, when I showed it to a native-speaker and asked if it was correct they did not understand. But I can't see what is wrong with it...

> 昨日時半間で昼寝しました。

What I tried to say:

> Yesterday I took a nap for an half hour.

Is this sentence incomprehensible?

Comment: Where did you learn to say 時半間?

Comment: @l'électeur Ohh, is the proper way to say it 半時間? Don't think I learned it anywhere if it's considered incorrect. I must have just done it wrong.

Comment: @macraf The sentence was in text-format on the app HiNative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「昨日{きのう}**時半間で**昼寝{ひるね}しました。」

By 「時半間」, you probably meant to say 「半時間{はんじかん}」 for "half an hour", but still we do not say 「半時間」 in Standard Japanese.  We say 「30分{ぷん}」.

I have heard that they say 「半時間」 to mean "half an hour" in Kansai (around Osaka, that is), but I am not sure if it is true.  Hope someone can confirm this.

Also important is that you do ***not*** need to place a particle after 「30分」.  It is not even optional; You cannot use a particle there.

So, you will have:

> 「昨日、30分昼寝（を）しました。」

Comment: even `30分の昼寝` doesn't work? I found this: http://mezamashi.jp/suimin/hirune/

Comment: ３０分の昼寝 is fine as a noun phrase.  When I said no particle was needed, I meant "in the sentence OP is trying to form".  In other words, I meant when ３０分 was directly followed by a verb.  All I wanted to say was that to say "did something for 30 minutes", you do not use a particle after 30分.